# How to use VPN(pptp) with golang net package?

Tags: go, vpn, pptp

I've bound several vpn on the server which is ppp0 ~ ppp4.
Now comes the problem.I want to start 5 progresses each one use the difference network interface.
proc0 -> ppp0
proc1 -> ppp1
proc2 -> ppp2
proc3 -> ppp3
proc4 -> ppp4
I now how to do this with c language.Just use setsockopt with parameter SO_BINDTODEVICE.
But how to do this with net package in golang?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [`net.Interfaces()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interfaces) to get a slice of [`net.Interface()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interface) representing the network interfaces on your system, or, as you know the interface names, you can use [`net.InterfaceByName()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#InterfaceByName) to get a particular `net.Interface`.

```
ppp0, err := net.InterfaceByName("ppp0")
```

You can then call [`Interface.Addrs()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interface.Addrs) on the returned `net.Interface` and get the interface's IP address(es).

```
addrs, err := ppp0.Addrs()
```

You can then use the desired address in the rest of your code (probably using [`net.ListenIP`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenIP) or [`net.DialIP`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#DialIP).

```
addr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip4", addrs[0])
// check err
conn, err := net.ListenIP("ip4:pptp", addr)
// check err, then do stuff with conn
```

Regarding doing this for more than one interface concurrently, you can launch a goroutine for each listener / interface, and move the traffic over channels, but this really depends on what you want to do. (are you just logging the data, sending  the data, modifying the data etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The dialer's LocalAddr doesn't work for ppp interfaces, we should set the `SOL_SOCKET` flag to socket using `setsockopt`, for go 1.11+ you can create a dialer like this

```golang
    dialer := net.Dialer{
        Control: func(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
            return c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
                err := syscall.SetsockoptString(int(fd), syscall.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "ppp0")
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("control: %s", err)
                    return
                }
            })
        },
    }
    // use the dialer
```